# What's my documentroot?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

**EDIT: I found it. It turned out to be**

`/home/spss01/domains/spss-tutorials.com/`

and I don't think I could have figured that out without the help of my hosting provider.

**END EDIT.**

For example, I've an image in a `downloads` folder whose url is

`http://spss-tutorials.com/downloads/decimals_histogram.png`

However, in FileZilla it looks rather differently (see screenshot below):

`/domains/spss-tutorials.com/public_html/downloads`

So what's my `documentroot`?

I'm asking this because I think I'm misspecifying the absolute path to an `.htpasswd` file in an `.htaccess` file, resulting in an `HTTP 500` internal server error.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: FYI, there are three different paths involved that don't necessarily have to match: HTTP, FTP and file system.

Answer (score 1):

If you look closely at the screenshot, you'll see that (and maybe infer that) you're in a shared hosting service. The hosting provider puts all domain names in a separate directory inside the `domains` directory.

Thus, your `DOCUMENT_ROOT` should be `/domains/spss-tutorials.com/public_html`

Comment: I already tried that and I still got the HTTP 500 error. Are you really sure? If so, then perhaps I should look for other possible causes for the error...

Comment: @RubenGeert Are you sure that the error is because of wrong path? Can you check logs?

Comment: @hjippoter92: thanks for the suggestion, also see the edit to my OP. It was the wrong path indeed but my hosting provider helped me out.